# Jade ternary operator add element

Tags: pug

Wondering if there is a way to write a ternary, or shorter form of if statement, which adds the 'a' element to the table cell when the if is satisfied.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
td= foo.x ? a(href="/#{foo.x}/foobar") View : '-'
```

The following does work, but is quite long winded and untidy..

```
tbody
each foo in bar
  tr
    td= foo.name
    if foo.x
      td
        a(href="/#{foo.x}/foobar") View
    else
      td -
    if foo.y
      td
        a(href="/#{foo.y}/hello") Hello
    else
      td -
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>No. There is no ternary operator (that I know of!) in Jade.</strike>As it turns out, there is a ternary operator. However, to shorten your code, what you could do is declare blocks and use them in your if/else sections. While this technically adds lines to your code, I think this helps you with your problem of long if/else statements.

Using your example:

```
block x_view
  td
    a(href="/#{foo.x}/foobar") View

block dash
  td -

block y_hello
  td
    a(href="/#{foo.y}/hello") Hello

tbody
each foo in bar
  tr
    td= foo.name
    if foo.x
      block x_view
    else
      block dash
    if foo.y
      block y_hello
    else
      block dash
```

Comment: @rjreed Oh strange, I could not find any docs on them or get them to work. I'll edit my post.

Comment: I posted a super simple working example below. They're dead useful.


The documentation for jade leaves a lot to be desired- maybe I'll make a pull request with a ternary examples for the docs.

Comment: @rjreed I probably forgot some simple thing when I tested... that said, there's nothing about them on the site (https://www.google.com/webhp#q=site%3Ajade-lang.com%20ternary) so I don't feel too bad

Answer (score 9):

Ternaries work fine in jade.

I did a quick working example loosely based on your question:

```
- var bar=[{name:'Joe',x:'something'},{name:'Mike'}]

each foo in bar
  p=foo.x ? foo.name + ' hasX' : foo.name + ' noX'
```

results in

```
<p>Joe hasX</p>
<p>Mike noX</p>
```

Comment: Although I haven't tried this, I don't believe you can add in jade elements in the parts of the ternary though? e.g. p=foo.x ? a(href='1234') foo.name + ' hasX' : foo.name + ' noX'

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work. There are hacks that work, though.

Example: http://codepen.io/rjreed/pen/zGeFh

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `#{}`:

```
h6 #{(employee.Sprite > 0) ? "SPRITE" : "NO SPRITE"}
```

Where employee.Sprite is a number in the data...