# pug add/remove class name by variable from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, jade4j

I have a pug template that should should display  red text when an error is returned and green text when an operation is successful.

I have difficulty setting the `<p/>` classname(s) based on the `status` response returned from my NodeJS backend.

My NodeJS renders my page as follows:

```
router.get('/forgot-password',
    session.ensureNotLoggedIn('/user/dashboard'),
    (req, res, next) => {
        res.render("forgot-password");
    });

router.post('/forgot-password',
    session.ensureNotLoggedIn('/user/logout'),
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.body.edtEmail) {
            res.render("forgot-password");
        }
        emailer.sendVerifyEmail().then(value => {
            res.render("forgot-password", {message: "Email sent, check your inbox!", status: true});
        }).catch(reason => {
            res.render("forgot-password", {message: "Failed to send email [" + reason + "]", status: false});
        })
    });
```

The key take away is the `{ message: [string], status: [bool] }`. I need to render the `message`, and based on the `status`, the  should either have a class `text-danger` or `text-success` if failed or successful respectively.

*Below are various methods I have tried without success. To clarify, the `status` value is `false` which should add `text-danger` class.*

---

In my pug template:

- I have **tried** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959388/4628115)):

  `p#lblMessage(class = status ? text-success : text-warning) #{message}`

rendering

```
<p id="lblMessage">Failed to send email [true]</p>
```

- **Tried** (source):

  `p#lblMessage(class="#{status ? text-success : text-warning}") #{message}`

rendering:

```
<p class="#{status ? text-success : text-warning}" id="lblMessage">Failed to send email [true]</p>
```

- **Tried** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13669249/4628115)):

  `p#lblMessage(class = "#{status ? text-success : text-warning}") #{message}`

rendering:

```
<p class="#{status ? text-success : text-warning}" id="lblMessage">Failed to send email [true]</p>
```

Doing something like this seems quite counter productive and ridiculous in the case of having multiple classes and states, etc (below which doesn't work ofc - most likely as I am doing something wrong: [source](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html)).

```
if (status)
    p.text-success#lblMessage #{message}
else
    p.text-warning#lblMessage #{message}
```

**How can I use variables passed from NodeJS backend to add/alter/remove classes of html elements in pug template?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a conditional classname can be achieved by this:

```
p#lblMessage(class=(status  ? 'text-success' : 'text-warning')) #{message}
```

To explain the difference between above code and your mentioned [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959388/4628115):

The `class` attribute is getting a string, pug use this as value. If a boolean is returned (or null), the attribute self gets rendered or not. E.g. a checkbox:

```
input(type='checkbox', checked=(1===1 ? true : false))
input(type='checkbox', checked=(1===2 ? true : false))

rendered to:

<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: will post my solution below for the record, but accept yours

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, more reading/searching, etc I found a working solution. I do not recommend using my solution, I am posting it as a 'stepping stone' of how I cam to a solution based on my reading up on suggestions, forums, etc.

*Note, I wasn't aware of the parenthesis `()` syntax at the point of finding a solution*

```
//this first line is in the case of a GET, so the <p/> isn't rendered
if status !== undefined
    p#lblMessage(class=status ? "text-success" : "text-danger") #{message}
```

Using WebStorm, I noticed a possible syntax error (however the page compiled correctly):
[image]

I suggest to use @kmgt's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63506226/4628115) instead

Comment: Same squiggly red line in vscode when expression is not set in parentheses.